# Timeout for long-running queries with RODBC & MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, r, odbc, rodbc

I have to run an SQL query that iterates cursor over a larger table (MS SQL Server 2014). It would be rather difficult not to use a cursor for this particular purpose.

The cursor-related code is kept in a stored procedure. R only evaluated `EXEC dbo.do_something`. `EXEC dbo.do_something` works as expected when running the code from MS SQL Management Studio. When I run it via RODBC, the query aborts without error message after 30 secs. I guess this is the value of "Connection Timeout".

What options do I have to make the query work with R?

Comment: Connection Timeout (which can be set on the connection string) is the time allowed to connect to the server. Command Timeout, the time allowed for a command to execute, is usually set on the command object in code (C#, VB etc) and afaik there's no way to set this on a per-connection basis. RODBC doesn't seem to mention timeouts (or I couldn't find anything) in the manual, so I'm guessing it doesn't expose the ODBC API to alter the command timeout, which seems limiting.

Comment: @les-h Thanks for the clarification. I guess I'll have to take a different route to run this query.

Comment: I am currently implementing the **query timeout** (command timeout) feature in the package `RODBCext` and publish it within the next weeks. See: https://github.com/zozlak/RODBCext/issues/10

Comment: @RYoda Is it possible to somehow port the query timeout implementation to de dbi odbc package? (I would really appreciate it if you would take a look at my question [r odbc query timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74143685/r-odbc-query-timeout)

Comment: @Odrai Ewh, I have implemented this in RODBCext many years ago (even though it was not too difficult). I saw you have already opened an [issue](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/515) for that at `r-dbi/odbc` (incl. a very good description). Let's wait a little bit and see if Jim Hester is implementing this (he knows the underlying nanodbc c++ library far better than I do...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the answer to my particular problem is rather simple: Add `SET NOCOUNT ON` to the proc definition.