# R odbc query timeout

Tags: r, sql-server, timeout, odbc

Previously the RODBCext package provided an option to set the [**query timeout**](https://github.com/zozlak/RODBCext/blob/master/R/odbcSetQueryTimeout.R). As of 2020 the package is deprecated and the better alternative is [odbc](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc) ([cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odbc/index.html)).

This odbc package doesn't seem to provide the described option. I was wondering if there is another way around to implement a query timeout while using odbc (perhaps something like the [C code](https://github.com/zozlak/RODBCext/blob/master/src/RODBCext.c#L426) of the RODBCext package which sets the value of SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT).

(R does have a [withTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70993017/1974344) function, but I want to have a reliable/ correct implementation)

Comment: Hello, `odbc::dbConnect` generic for S4 object `OdbcDriver`  has the `timeout` parameter. See `library(odbc); getMethod("dbConnect",c(drv="OdbcDriver"))` or the help `?odbc::dbConnect`

Comment: @RicVillalba The timeout within dbConnect is: 'Time in seconds to timeout the **connection attempt**. Setting a timeout of Inf indicates no timeout. (defaults to 10 seconds).' I am looking for a **query** timeout (not a connection timeout).

Comment: I've created a pull request which adds the query_timeout option to the odbc package: [GitHub link](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/pull/517)